# Saveinbackgroundwithblock not executing

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am new to using swift/**Parse** and am having difficulty updating a user column in _User. The issue is that **Parse** is already running `getObjectinBackgroundWithId`, and the `saveInBackground` does not run (no success or error). If I run `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` without retrieving the user by their id, I have no problem saving.

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var current = PFUser.currentUser().objectId
    var userId = self.dictionary[indexPath.row]["userId"]
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    var user: PFObject?
    self.query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(userId) {
        (success: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success != nil {
            success.addUniqueObject(current, forKey: "friendRequest")
            user = success
        }
    }
    var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    else {
        self.searchController.active = false
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Are you sure you want to add \(cell!.textLabel!.text!) to your friends?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { (action) in
            user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if success == true {
                    println("worked")
                }
                else {
                    println(error)
                }
            }
        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand your issue. The reason you use `saveInBackground ` is not to get the answer back immediately. So, if you want to get the answer back right away, just use `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: @LucasHuang: FYI, we do indeed say "any help" in English, *not* "any helps".

Comment: Alright. Thx anyway. @ruakh

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this? Having the same issue, albeit with Objective-c.